# Why can I not change the size of my Panel in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to build a collapsible panel by having a control with a header and a panel. When someone clicks on the header the panel should collapse/expand.

However when I add another control inside the body of the collapsible panel which is a `Panel`, the width and height seem to be locked therefore they cannot be changed. My understanding was disabling `AutoSize` would allow me to freely resize the panel but obviously not. What am I missing here?

```
internal sealed class CollapsiblePanel : Control
{
    private const string DownIconBase64 = "AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAREQCQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAYHByQGBwckQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAcHByQBAgLhAQIC4QYHByRAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAYHByQBAgLhAQIC/wEBAf8BAgLhBgcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAYGBiQBAgLhAQIC/wECAt0BAgLfAQEB/wECAuEGBwckQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQBAgLhAQEB/wECAt8HBwciBwcHIAECAt8BAQH/AQIC4UBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEAQEB/wECAuEGBwciQEREBEBERAQHBwcgAQIC3wEBAf9AREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAECAuEGBwckQEREBAYGBiQGBwckQEREBAcHByABAgLfQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBwckQEREBAYGBiQBAgLhAQIC4QYHByRAREQEBwcHIEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAYHByQBAgLhAQEB/wECAv8BAgLhBgcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAcHByQBAgLhAQIC/wECAt0BAgLdAQIC/wECAuEGBwckQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQBAgLhAQIC/wECAt8HBwciBwgIIAECAt0BAgL/AQIC4UBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEAQIC/wECAt8HCAgiQEREBEBERAQHCAggAQIC3QECAv9AREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAECAuEHBwckQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAcICCABAgLdQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBgYkQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEBwgIIEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==";
    private const string UpIconBase64 = "AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAREQCQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAcHByBAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBgYkQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQBAgLdBwcHIEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBwckAQIC4UBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEAQIC/wECAt0HBwcgQEREBEBERAQHBwciAQIC3wEBAf9AREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAECAuEBAgL/AQIC3QcHByAHCAgiAQIC3wECAv8BAgLhQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQHBwckAQIC4QECAv8BAgLdAQIC3QECAv8BAgLhBgcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAcHByQBAgLhAQIC/wECAv8BAgLhBwcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAcICCBAREQEBwcHJAECAuEBAgLhBgcHJEBERAQHBwckQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQBAgLdBwgIIEBERAQHBwckBgYGJEBERAQHBwckAQIC4UBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAJAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEAQEB/wECAt0HCAggQEREBEBERAQGBwciAQIC3wECAv9AREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBAECAuMBAQH/AQIC3QcICCAHBwciAQIC3wEBAf8BAgLhQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBgYmAQIC4wEBAf8BAgLdAQIC3QEBAf8BAgLhBgYGJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBAYGBiYBAgLjAQEB/wECAv8BAgLhBgYGJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEBgYGJgECAuMBAgLhBgcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREAkBERAJAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERAQGBgYmBwcHJEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQEQEREBEBERARAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCQEREAkBERAJAREQCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==";

    private static readonly Image DownIcon = DownIconBase64.ToImage();
    private static readonly Image UpIcon = UpIconBase64.ToImage();
    private readonly Button _headerButton;
    private readonly Panel _body;
    private int _width, _height;
    private bool _isCollapsed;

    public CollapsiblePanel(string name)
    {
        _body = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, AutoSize = false };

        _headerButton = new Button
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Top,
            Text = name,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            Image = DownIcon,
            ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight,
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = false
        };

        _headerButton.Click += (_, __) =>
        {
            if (_isCollapsed)
            {
                Expand();
            }
            else
            {
                Collapse();
            }
        };

        Controls.Add(_body);
        Controls.Add(_headerButton);

        ControlAdded += (_, eArgs) => { _body.Controls.Add(eArgs.Control); };
        ControlRemoved += (_, eArgs) => { _body.Controls.Remove(eArgs.Control); };
    }

    public void Collapse()
    {
        _width = _body.Width;
        _height = _body.Height;

        _body.Width = 0;
        _body.Height = 0;
        _headerButton.Image = UpIcon;

        _isCollapsed = true;
    }

    public void Expand()
    {
        _body.Width = _width;
        _body.Height = _height;
        _headerButton.Image = DownIcon;

        _isCollapsed = false;
    }
}

internal static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given <paramref name="base64Input"/> to <see cref="Image"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static Image ToImage(this string base64Input)
    {
        var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of working with the size, can you simply change the Visible property to true/false?

Comment: Awesome buddy! Simple yet effective :-) Feel free to post that as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot easier to work just with the Visible property like

```
public void Collapse()
{
    _body.Visible = false;
    _headerButton.Image = UpIcon;
    _isCollapsed = true;
}

public void Expand()
{
    _body.Visible = true;
    _headerButton.Image = DownIcon;
    _isCollapsed = false;
}
```

No need to keep around _width, _height values to restore the size.

Answer (score 3):

The `Fill` docking makes it to fix the size. You may want to change the `Fill` property when you collapse or expand.

```
    public void Collapse()
    {
        _width = _body.Width;
        _height = _body.Height;

        _body.Dock = DockStyle.None;

        _body.Width = 0;
        _body.Height = 0;
        _headerButton.Image = UpIcon;

        _isCollapsed = true;
    }

    public void Expand()
    {
        _body.Width = _width;
        _body.Height = _height;
        _body.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _headerButton.Image = DownIcon;

        _isCollapsed = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **Dock** property of your panel (*_body*) to **None**

Comment: If I do that, then any control that I add to the collapsible panel covers over it. You can try that by adding let's say a `DataGridView` to the collapsible panel.